# Can we use <body> in place of #container div?

Tags: css, xhtml

Can we give width and border to `<body>` and use in place of Container div? [see this example](http://jitendravyas.com/css/bodywidth.html)

see source code of this file and code of file is also perfectly W3C valid. and looking same in IE 7 and firefox 3.5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title> Width in body</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { background-color: #00f; }
     body{background: #cd5c5c;width:800px;height:400px;border:1px solid;color: #fff;margin:0 auto;}
     </style>
  </head>
   <body>
     <p>Hello world!</p>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Closed as not a real question, say several people. Actually, it's a perfectly valid question, with interesting answers. Of course, now that the question has been killed, nobody will get to explore this question here. Rather sad. We might have talked about the fact that in some browsers, one used to use a min-width css property on body to assure that content could be seen even in smaller browser situations. This question is a lost opportunity.

Comment: OP needs to provide sample code in the post rather than a link to his web site. As it stands, this post reeks of an effort to promote the OPs web site.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür  Who is op? code added

Comment: OP means you, the original poster. And thanks for adding the sample code!

Comment: @Pablo thx. my purpose was not promote my site. I've nothing to promote.

Comment: I personally think it's ludicrous to object to people posting links to actual code rather than cut-and-pasting the code in place. For anything but the most trivial HTML/CSS/JS question, the only way to properly debug it is as a live page. I've seen a number of questions where I would have been able to give a definitive answer within a minute, but I didn't have time to copy-and-paste all the material (if in fact it was all provided) and deploy it to localhost, potentially having to set up some mock PHP or similar to replicate Ajax interactions. Downvoting because a link is provided is idiotic.

Comment: Furthermore, given that the link goes to a page that just says "Hello World" it can hardly be seen as self-promotion.

Comment: My question is why w3c supporting width and height in <body> what is use of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example answers your question!  Body is a block element like any other.  It has width, height, padding, margin and border properties.

- Note that it is essential that the page is rendered in strict, rather than quirks, mode to be able to treat the body element as a block-level element; otherwise it is treated as the documentElement and all bets are off. – NickFitz

Then can we use body in place of #container div? – Jitendra

- Nice theory. Shame about Microsoft. – David Dorward
- @Jitendra: you can, but be thorough with your cross-browser testing, particularly when it comes to scrolling :-) – NickFitz

What is the difference between viewport and body? – Jitendra

- the viewport is the visible area of the browser window which displays the document. The body is an element in the document. In quirks mode, the body will also be treated as the documentElement: that is, the root node of the document, which will fill the window, and if necessary will be able to be scrolled. In strict mode, the html element will be treated as the documentElement, and the body will be a child of that. As an experiment, change your test page by adding the style rule html { background-color: #00f; } - you will see that the html element contains the `body' – NickFitz

Comment: then can we use body in place of #container  div?

Comment: Nice theory. Shame about Microsoft.

Comment: Note that it is essential that the page is rendered in strict, rather than quirks, mode to be able to treat the `body` element as a block-level element; otherwise it is treated as the `documentElement` and all bets are off.

Comment: What is the difference between viewport and body?

Comment: @Jitendra: the viewport is the visible area of the browser window which displays the document. The `body` is an element in the document. In quirks mode, the `body` will also be treated as the `documentElement`: that is, the root node of the document, which will fill the window, and if necessary will be able to be scrolled. In strict mode, the `html` element will be treated as the `documentElement`, and the `body` will be a child of that. As an experiment, change your test page by adding the style rule `html { background-color: #00f; }` - you will see that the `html` element contains the `body'

Comment: @NickFitz thx for clarification. i updated my sample page. then in xhtml strict html is documentElement so can we use body as container in place of #container div

Comment: @Jitendra: you can, but be thorough with your cross-browser testing, particularly when it comes to scrolling :-)

Comment: @NickFitz you mean in xhtml strict div and body are same in beh?aviour

Comment: I found more knowledge from here http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/02/11/styling-the-html-and-body-elements/